# Solve System of Equations to find LFSR coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, cryptography

Let the sequence $(s_n)_n$ be generated by an LFSR (linear feedback shift register) of order $k$. We know $s_0,\dots,s_{2k-1}$ and want to determine $a_0,\dots,a_{k-1}$. If the solution is not unique, show that every solution leads to the sequence $(s_n)_n$.

My attempt: We know that $s_{n+k}=a_{k-1}s_{n+k-1}+\dots+a_os_n$ for $n\geq 0$ (where $a_i\in\mathbb{F_q}$. This implies the following set of equations:
$$
s_k=a_{k-1}s_{k-1}+\dots+a_0s_0\\
s_{k+1}=a_{k-1}s_{k}+\dots+a_0s_1\\
\vdots\\
s_{2k-1}=a_{k-1}s_{2k-2}+\dots+a_0s_{k-1}
$$
but I do not know how to proceed. Is there a simple way of solving such a large system of equations?

Comment: To specify: Do you want an explicit formula for the solution, or just that every solution works for our purposes?

Comment: An explicit formula ideally - it's easy to see that every solution works.

Answer (score 1):

The unknown vector in this case is $a = [a_{k-1}, a_{k-2}, \dots, a_1, a_0] $, you can build the system

$ S a = v $

where

$ S = \begin{bmatrix} s_{k-1}&& s_{k-2}&& \dots && s_1 && s_0 \\ 
s_{k}&& s_{k-1}&& \dots && s_2 && s_1 \\
\vdots && \vdots && \vdots && \vdots && \vdots \\
s_{2k-2}&& s_{2k-1}&& \dots && s_{k-2} && s_{k-1} \end{bmatrix}$

And

$ v = \begin{bmatrix} s_k \\ s_{k+1} \\ \vdots \\ s_{2k-1} \end{bmatrix} $

Then the unknown vector is given by

$ a = S^{-1} v $